# Type 'BannerView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable' GoogleMobileAds 11.0.0

Tags: swiftui, google-mobile-ads

I am using **GoogleMobileAds 11.0.0** and facing issue as below -

> Type 'BannerView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerRepresentable'

[image]

After fix, getting `func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {` while this method is already present.

Google Referance: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/main/Swift/advanced/SwiftUIDemo

```swift
import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct BannerContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BannerView()
    }
}

struct BannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @State private var viewWidth: CGFloat = .zero
    private let bannerView = GADBannerView()
    private let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2435281174"
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        let bannerViewController = BannerViewController()
        bannerView.adUnitID = adUnitID
        bannerView.rootViewController = bannerViewController
        bannerView.delegate = context.coordinator
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bannerViewController.view.addSubview(bannerView)
        // Constrain GADBannerView to the bottom of the view.
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: bannerViewController.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            bannerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerViewController.view.centerXAnchor),
        ])
        bannerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return bannerViewController
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        guard viewWidth != .zero else { return }
        
        bannerView.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth)
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate, GADBannerViewDelegate
    {
        let parent: BannerView
        
        init(_ parent: BannerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // MARK: - BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate methods
        
        func bannerViewController(
            _ bannerViewController: BannerViewController, didUpdate width: CGFloat
        ) {
            parent.viewWidth = width
        }
        
        // MARK: - GADBannerViewDelegate methods
        
        func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
            print("DID RECEIVE AD")
        }
        
        func bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
            print("DID NOT RECEIVE AD: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

protocol BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate: AnyObject {
    func bannerViewController(_ bannerViewController: BannerViewController, didUpdate width: CGFloat)
}

class BannerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    weak var delegate: BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        delegate?.bannerViewController(
            self, didUpdate: view.frame.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets).size.width)
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(
        to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator
    ) {
        coordinator.animate { _ in
            // do nothing
        } completion: { _ in
            self.delegate?.bannerViewController(
                self, didUpdate: self.view.frame.inset(by: self.view.safeAreaInsets).size.width)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help how to fix. Am I missing aything to add?

1 more question as - not able to get **kGADAdSizeBanner** in version **GoogleMobileAds 11.0.0**. How can I get this?

Comment: I tried the code above, it builds success. Do you try to clean and build again?

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. Actually I has a protocol UIViewControllerType locally. After renaming protocol, got fixed. Thanks

Comment: You should never use Apple prefixes (such as UI) for your own code.